# Combine CASE and BETWEEN in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I'm trying to execute what I presumed to be a simple enough query, however I'm encountering syntax errors and could use some guidance. Essentially I have a function with a text input parameter `$1`. This parameter can take on 7 different values controlled by the front end of an application.

Depending on the value of this parameter, I need to return a subset of a larger table between a certain range of one of the integer columns returned. To be slightly clearer, the returning query within the function looks something like:

```
SELECT val_1, val_2, val_3
  FROM schema_name.table_name
 WHERE val_3 BETWEEN
  CASE WHEN $1 = 'a' THEN 0 AND 1
       WHEN $1 = 'b' THEN 2 AND 7
         .
         . 
         .
       WHEN $1 = 'g' THEN 50 AND 100
   END;
```

However, I'm getting a typically vague error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 42:    END;
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at end of input
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1133
```

The ranges set out in the case statement all differ, with no discernible pattern between them. I could of course write an `IF` block with 7 `ELSE` statements essentially writing the same select statement 7 times, but I'm guessing the above can't be too far off. I've never had the need to use a `CASE` statement in a `WHERE` clause in this way before. Any hints in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [**`CASE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression can only return a *single value* (`boolean` in my fixed version), not conditional code like you tried:

```
SELECT val_1, val_2, val_3
FROM   schema_name.table_name
WHERE  CASE $1
         WHEN 'a' THEN val_3 BETWEEN 0 AND 1
         WHEN 'b' THEN val_3 BETWEEN 2 AND 7
          . 
          .
          .
         WHEN 'g' THEN val_3 BETWEEN 50 AND 100
       END;
```

Using the "simple" form of [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) to make it slightly shorter and faster.

Alternatively, just use boolean logic only:

```
...
WHERE (
       $1 = 'a' AND val_3 BETWEEN 0 AND 1
   OR  $1 = 'b' AND val_3 BETWEEN 2 AND 7
         . 
         .
         .
   OR  $1 = 'g' AND val_3 BETWEEN 50 AND 100
      )
```

Parentheses are not strictly needed since [operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) works in our favor anyway. `AND` binds before `OR` and `BETWEEN` binds before both. But you'll need those parentheses if you add another `WHERE` condition with `AND`.

#### Performance?

For both variants, Postgres 12 (didn't test for earlier versions) is smart enough to still use an index on `(val_3)` or not, depending on actual column statistics. Even for prepared statements.

**If** that function is called a lot,
and you work with prepared statements (directly or indirectly),
and performance is critical,
and some of your ranges benefit from an index while others don't
then you might still fork (at least) two distinct queries in order to work with generic, saved query plans for either case to get absolute best performance.

Comment: An excellent answer, and very well explained. Both methods are concise and perform well. Many thanks..

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression returns 1 scalar value and not 2 or an interval of values.
What you can do is use it as a query cross joined to the table:

```
SELECT t.val_1, t.val_2, t.val_3
FROM schema_name.table_name t
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT CASE $1 
       WHEN 'a' THEN 0
       WHEN 'b' THEN 1
         .
   END val
) c
WHERE t.val_3 BETWEEN 2 * c.val AND 2 * c.val + 1
```

Edit.
You can use a `CTE` which returns all the possible values of `$1` and the intervals for each value:

```
WITH cte(val, min, max) AS (
  VALUES ('a', 0, 1), ('b', 2, 7), .........  
)  
SELECT t.val_1, t.val_2, t.val_3
FROM table_name t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE val = $1) c
WHERE t.val_3 BETWEEN c.min AND c.max
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @forpas. Apologies, I see now that my question was slightly too general. Although your answer does work for the intervals I've added, the actual intervals go from 0 to 1, then 2 to 7,, then 8 to 30, so on so forth with no numerical pattern, so the WHERE t.val_3 BETWEEN 2 * c.val AND 2 * c.val + 1 wouldn't cut it.. Apologies again, I'll update the question.